# How to send vCard or MMS with Clickatell

Tags: mms, vcf-vcard, clickatell

Hello Clickatell Support

We are a customer of yours in Australia and have been unable to get **any** response from support regarding cases created on the website.

We are in dire need of assistance to send **vCard** and **MMS** messages via Clickatell. The documentation is non-existent when it comes to sending these.

Please let us know what we need to send to the API to do this. Or let us know if you can't so we can find a different provider.

Comment: Related link with reference to vCARD: https://archive.clickatell.com/developers/2015/10/08/http/s/

Answer (score 1):

I asked Clickatell support and got this response:

> The sending of MMS or binary messaging is supported. You would need to know how to construct the message though.

That's it. No documentation on how to send a binary message or any examples. :(

Comment: We abandoned the approach of sending a vCard via MMS with them and went with sending a HTTP link instead (using shortener service like bit.ly). The biggest reason was because it didn't work for iPhone. We did manage to get it going on Android (Samsung/OnePlus) but iPhone just flat out didn't do anything. I used the MMS Composer (refer sendsms.com) but that too is old and dated tech. Also, we found that Telstra's own API was really good and fast too, fwiw. FYI, with iPhone, if your link it at the start or the end of the SMS, it will do a preview implicitly. Hth.

Answer (score 0):

according to my knowledge, Clickatell does not support MMS or VCARD messages.